# Using @Slf4j annotation for logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

First of all I will give a brief explanation about the scenario. In my application I am using SLF4J as the logging facade. For logging, I am using Log4j2 and I have my customized `log4j2.xml` as well.
When I log in my classes, I create a logger as mentioned below:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TestController.class);
```

Later, I found out that there is a `@Slf4j` annotation and then I can log without creating a logger instance manually.

```
log.info("Info log in getHello() in TestController");
```

I did a minor research about the topic where is there any drawbacks of using `@Slf4j` annotation, instead of creating a logger instance within the class. I did not come across any reason why shouldn't use `@Slf4j` annotation.

However, before proceeding I wanted to ask from this community to confirm is there any drawback of using `@Slf4j`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation of `@Log` and friends](https://projectlombok.org/features/log):

> ...
>
> `@Slf4j`
>
> Creates `private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);`
>
> ...

We see that this is equivalent to

```
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TestController.class);
```

aside from the name of the field.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85! is there any drawbacks of using Slf4j annotation ?

Comment: Only the normal drawbacks that you get when using lombok: relying on an undocumented compiler-api that could change without prior notice and break lombok.

Comment: Great. So where do I put that annotation?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz you haven't read the documentation I've linked in my answer, have you?

Comment: I didn't read it carefully enough. Now I see it goes on the class.

Answer (score 7):

```
@Slf4j
```

The above annotation from lombok creates a slf4j based Logger, but you would be requiring a log4j based logger. So don't feel you could use slf4j based logger.

If you plan to user slf4j based logger, lombok modifies the code and creates code during the **compile** phase not during runtime like cglib or using reflections. This would mean there won't be any dip in the performance.